# php usort - function 'comp' not found or invalid function name

Tags: php

I'm trying to sort an array based on the values within the array. I've tried the following

```
function comp($a, $b)
{
        return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
}
```

in my functions class, but when call it from the same class

```
    $usersInSection = $userManager->getUsersInSection($section);
    usort($usersInSection, "conp");
```

i get the message

> usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'comp'
>   not found or invalid function name

Comment: I assume you mean `usort($usersInSection, "comp");` not what you have which is 'conp'. Close... Update your question if you corrected it and it stiil doesn't work. Tell us the next error you have. Err, what do you mean _'functions class'_!?

Comment: The `function` 'comp()' declared globally and the `instance method` of `$this->comp()` and the `static class method` of `static function comp()` as 'self::comp()'. Are all completely separate things. Which do you have? They are all called in different ways as `callbacks` in `usort`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax to call usort with a callback inside a class is:

```
usort($usersInSection, array("MyClass", "comp"));
```

Check the [PHP Manual: Callbacks / Callables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)

Answer (score 14):

If your comp is in a class then it's a method.

To use it in same class methods you need to call like this:

```
usort($usersInSection, array($this, "comp"));
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have a typo in `usort($usersInSection, "conp")`. your function is called `comp` not `conp`.

Comment: Realised that after posting and corrected it but the issue persists

Answer (score 0):

> in my functions class

So you have a class to hold helper functions(?), and therefor `comp` is actually a *method* of that class?

Then you have to pass the class name or a class instance (for non-static method) to `usort`, in the same way as described in the [manual for `call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).